# Law of Iterated Logarithm for Fractional Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

(Cross-posted to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/281342/reference-for-lil-for-fractional-brownian-motion.)

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\Bbb P)$ be a complete probability space.

If $B=(B_t)_{t\ge0}$ is a standard real valued Brownian Motion on this space, then the following things are well known:

1. The trajectories of $B$ are a.s. $\alpha$-Holder continuous for all $0<\alpha<1/2$.
2. $B\notin\operatorname{BV}[0,T]$ but a.s. $B$ has finite quadratic variation, and if I remember well this is the best possible, in sense that a.s. $\|B\|_p=+\infty$ for every $p<2$ (here $\|\cdot\|_p$ is the $p$-variation norm on the fixed interval $[0,T]$).
3. A.s. the law of iterated logarithm says that
   $$ \limsup_{t\to0^+}\frac{B_t}{\sqrt{2t\log\log(1/t)}}=1$$
   $$ \liminf_{t\to0^+}\frac{B_t}{\sqrt{2t\log\log(1/t)}}=-1$$
   4.Set $S_t:=\sup_{0\le s\le t}B_s$ and fixed $a>0$, then reflection principle ensures that
   $$
   \Bbb P(S_t\ge a)=\Bbb P(|B_t|\ge a)
   $$
   from which we get the distribution of $S$.

My questions are: what can we say about the Fractional Brownian Motion $B^H$ of Hurst parameter $0<H<1$ (I'm particularly interested in the case of $1/2<H<1$)? And what about $|B^H|$?

1. It is well known that a.s. $B^H$ has trajectories which are $\alpha$-Holder continuous for all $0<\alpha<H$; the same holds for $|B^H|$ since the composition of an $\alpha$-Holder and a $\beta$-Holder function is $\alpha\beta$-Holder continous.
2. I'm not sure, but it seems reasonable that $\|B^H\|_{1/H}<+\infty$ and $\|B^H\|_p=+\infty$ for every $p<1/H$.

> What about $|B^H|$?
>
> For the third property, I don't know neither how to conjecture an analogous claim.

4. Is it true that, putting $S_t^H:=\sup_{0\le s\le t}B_t^H$
   $$
   \Bbb P(S_t^H\ge a)=\Bbb P(|B_t^H|\ge a)\;?
   $$

> What about $|S_t^H|:=\sup_{0\le s\le t}|B_t^H|$.

I bet all these properties are collected somewhere, in some lecture note, so any appropriate reference can be a perfect answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The exact modulus of continuity for fBm is $\delta^{H} |\log \delta|^{1/2}$, see e.g. Lifshitz *Gaussian Random Functions*, p. 220. In particular, it is $\alpha$-Hölder for any $\alpha\in (0,H)$.
2. This is very well known and is written in many introductory texts about fBm, see e.g. Nourdin *Selected Aspects of Fractional Brownian Motion*, Corollary 2.1.
3. Yes, there is a law of iterated logarithm 
   $$
   \limsup_{t\to 0+} \frac{B_t^H}{t^H|2\log\log t|^{1/2}} = 1
   $$
   almost surely, see [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/35ae/350b57da11ccf1219f4a27317d2b095d0db1.pdf), p. 36.
4. No, neither of this is true. The distribution of maximum of fBm (or its absolute value) is quite involved.

Comment: MANY MANY MANY MANY THANKS!!!

Comment: @Joe, no problem. I'm not very sure about exact form of the LIL, you need to check the references.

Comment: No problem, and thanks again!

Comment: Zhoraster, hoping not to abuse of your kindness, I ask you a quick question: I suppose a theory of stochastic integration wrt fractional BM already exists: can you give me some good reference please? In particular I'm interested in the equivalent of the Ito Isometry. In this paper by Nualart http://www.icm2006.org/proceedings/Vol_III/contents/ICM_Vol_3_74.pdf such a formula is given only for determinist processes: does it exists for random processes? Hoping not abusing of your patience, I thank you sincerely

Comment: @Joe, 1) this is not a desirable way to ask questions on this site; 2) yes, the theory exists, check references in Nourdin's book.

Comment: I ask you sorry, I didn't want to disrespect you or any other here. And most of all thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not lazy, I'm not abusing of your patience/time/kindness, believe me. I searched many many times before writing you for this. Thanks for all.

Comment: @zhoraster please take a look: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/281342/reference-for-lil-for-fractional-brownian-motion/281343#281343

Comment: @AlexanderChervov, I hate this way of cross-posting so I won't leave comment on MO (I hope the question there will be closed). Anyway, the link you give there speak about LIL for *local times*, not for fBm.

Answer (score 1):

You may find your result in the paper of kubilius et al. (2015, EJOS) see [here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ejs/1440507394)

From Eq. (8) in kubilius et al. (2015, EJOS), for any $\alpha>0$, we can see that
\begin{eqnarray}
\sup_{0\leq u\leq t}\left|B_{u}^{H}\right|&\leq&
t^{H+\alpha}\zeta\,,
\end{eqnarray}
where $\zeta$ is a nonnegative random variable and $\zeta$ has the following property: there exists $C > 0$ such that $\mathbb{E}\left[e^{x\zeta^{2}}\right]<\infty$,
for any $0< x< C$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Thus, taking a particular trajectory of the fBM (i.e. fixing an $\omega\in\Omega$) we would have $\sup_{0\le u\le t}|B_u^H(\omega)|\le t^{H+\alpha}\zeta(\omega)$, where $\zeta(\omega)\ge0$ is now a constant, right?

Comment: You can say that if $\alpha$ is situable.