# The law of iterated logarithm for the Fractional Brownian motion

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am searching for a reference for the law of iterated logarithm for the fractional Brownian motion.

As seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2377810/law-of-iterated-logarithm-for-fractional-brownian-motion) a LIL for the fBM is given, but the author of the answer is not sure about the form of that $\limsup$; nevertheless he gives a reference (the Lifshits book). I searched in it profusely. I found a *functional law* of the IL, but it seems working only on the standard BM.

Then I tried to search following the author of the LIL for fBM: Oodaira, without finding anything.

Finally I searched on the web, but -and this sounds quite strange!- without any significant result.

Can someone give me a precise reference in which one can find the statement (and possibly, but not necessarily,the proof) of the law of the iterated logarithm for the fractional Brownian motion?